# aptana 3 how to get rid of ruby plugins

Tags: aptana

I was just wondering is it possible to **get rid of all this ruby stuff in aptana**
I don't need those kind of plugins, could i uninstall them? How?
Rspec, engine yard, heroku, rails, ruby commands bundlles.

Or is it possible maybe to install pure eclipse and add plugins, to achive same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is conceivably possible, but in practice, no.

Answer (score 0):

I asked that same question to Aptana themselves and the answer is no.